# how to accomplish the video chat between ios devices using AVFoundation framework and asp.net ( server side)

Tags: iphone, avfoundation, videochat

I want to make a video chat app which allows two users to do video chat using there iphones or ipad2, I started with using AVFoundation framework and using socket connection (CFStreams) to open a socket connection with my server (server side language is asp.net) let me explain in detail what I have achieved till now :)

1) I created avcapture session which gives the frames at regular intervals using captureOutput:didOutputSampleBuffer:fromConnection delegate.
2) I have established a socket connection to my server and have obtained two streams
3) In the delegate I convert the sample buffer in to (uint8_t *)buffer and send to my output stream
4) at .net end I write those bytes in a file 
5) when my stream delegates receives the data back from server I create a assest with the url of the file made in server, create a avplayeritem and then play it in avplayer.

unfortunately it does not show anything.. please can anyone give me directions regarding whether this approach is right or wrong, what else I can do to achieve my aim?

Comment: When you say you convert the sample buffer to a (uint8_t *)buffer, what exactly do you mean? A CMSampleBuffer isn't itself meant to be transmittable.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are writing out to a file unnecessarily. If this was me, when I receive the sample buffer I would just display it in a UIView directly. There should be plenty of guides and sample projects around for this.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would have got an answer, if not try using [Wowza Media server](http://www.wowza.com/) with [RTMP library](http://ios-rtmp-library.com/). But both of these involves a cost for using. But definitely this will help you acheive what you were looking for.